# Can't create an XML node using Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I am trying to create a simple XML node with text "New node!"

```js
var xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("myFile.xml");
var newElem = xmlDoc.createElement("elem");
newElem.innerHTML = "New node!";
```

Where `loadXMLDoc()` is

```js
function loadXMLDoc(dname) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", dname, false);
    xhttp.send();
    return xhttp.responseXML;
}
```

But the code does not work. I expect the XML file to have a new node "<elem>" with "New node!" in it, but it was still the same. I have no idea why. There were no error messages.

How do I get my code to work?

Comment: What do you mean by "the code does not work"? What are you expecting?

Comment: @chris97ong There you go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call/16825593#16825593

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum the OP is making a synchronous request (`false` parameter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is creating a new element, but you are not appending it to the XML.

See the example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement#Example

Comment: So how do I change my JS code? Sry I'm a beginner of XML.

Comment: Did you look at the example? You need to use appendChild on the node where you want `elem` inserted.

Comment: My `elem` is not a child of any node

Comment: I tried:

`var newElem = xmlDoc.createElement("elem");
var newElemTxt = xmlDoc.createTextNode("New node!");
newElem.appendChild(newElemTxt);`

But not working

Comment: @chris97ong `elem` has to be a child of a node (root element or other).